# Is there a way for Drone to detect open-pull-request vs. push-on-pull-request event?

Tags: github, push, pull-request, drone.io

I have a use case that we want to automate testing with a Drone job and we notify stakeholders with the test results. We want to be able to test on every push on a pull request but we don't really want to notify on every subsequent pull request update.

So we need a way to only notify people with test results when a new Pull Request is opened, but not for its subsequent pushes. I am not sure if there's a way to do that with the When conditions. It also looks like that Push and Pull_request Github webhook will trigger separate Drone jobs

Comment: Can you clarify a couple of points? Are you using Drone 0.5+? Are you using an existing (community-provided) notification plugin, or are you creating your own?

Comment: @benschumacher i am using Latest drone so it is 0.5+x I am not using the default notification plugin 'cause it involves both Slack and Github comment. We send notification via Shell script. However, I believe somehow the when conditionals should be able to detect PR's action(opened, update, etc) but I have no clue how to make it work with current api available with Drone.